# How do you grid data based on three different arrays?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have three arrays. Time, height, and then my values at each time and height. It is a large dataset and when I try to do np.meshgrid() I get a memory error. When I plot it using plt.pcolormesh it plots perfectly.

For example, if I have an array of heights:

```
 [[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2],
  [-1,  0,  1, 2, 3, 4], 
  [ 1,  2,  3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

An array of times:

```
 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

And then my data:

```
 [[22, 10, 5, NaN, 3, 7],
  [4,   2, 9,  -3, 4, 1], 
  [7,   5, 2,  -1, 4, 2]]
```

How do I get a grid that looks something like this:

```
   -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
 1 22  10   5 NaN   3   7  NaN NaN NaN NaN
 2 NaN NaN  4   2   9  -3   4   1  NaN NaN
 3 NaN NaN NaN NaN  7   5   2  -1   4   2
```

I was then planning on making a Pandas DataFrame out of the data and using it for data analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and make your DataFrame and then just print it

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.columns = set(times)
df.index = set(heights)
for t, h, d in zip(times, heights, data):
    df[t].loc[h] = data
print(df)
```